# How to establish an IP conncetion with ModemManager, but without NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, modem, yocto

To test connectivity without NetworkManager, we would like to establish an IP connection using only ModemManager and basic Linux tools except NetworkManager, e.g. pppd. Our modem is a Telit HE-910 (3G) connected via USB. We're using Yocto-Linux. The only information I find about this is very vague. It would be really nice to have an example of how to use pppd then.

Comment: To voters to close as an off-topic: does not this question fit `Using or administering a *nix desktop or server` and `Applications packaged in *nix distributions` categories?

Comment: Take a look at `man mmcli` - the cli controlling ModemManager, namely `--simple-connect` command. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, --simple-connect works (regarding MM output). But I wanted to know how to use pppd (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what worked so far:

I put a chatscript into `/etc/chatscripts/` and a peers file into `/etc/ppp/peers/` . Then, after starting the ModemManager, I connect the modem:

```
mmcli -m 0 --simple-connect="apn=<our_apn>"
```

and then

```
pppd call provider
```

So it seems my questions is answered with this.